# How to import a .csv table with a foreign key into a django database

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys, import-from-csv

This is my first Django project and I am having difficulty loading data from a .csv file into a model with a foreign key.

Here are my models:

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    artistID = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, null=False, unique=True)
    artistName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    artistNotes = models.TextField(blank=True)

class Art(models.Model):
    artID = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, null=False, unique=True)
    artistID = models.ForeignKey(Artist, db_column='artistID', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default = 1)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, default = "No Title Given")
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    owner = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    origin = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    medium = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    artNotes = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

I wrote a view that would import the data:

```
def importArt(request):
    myFile = open('misc/Art.csv', 'r')
    for line in myFile:
        line = line.split(',')
        temp = Art.objects.create()
        temp.artID = line[0]
        temp.artistID = line[1]
        temp.title = line[2]
        temp.location = line[3]
        temp.owner = line[4]
        temp.origin = line[5]
        temp.medium = line[6]
        temp.artNotes = line[7]
        temp.save()
    myFile.close()
    return render(request, 'dtccArt/importArt.html', {})
```

This strategy worked fine for the Artist table but this is the error that I am getting:  Cannot assign "'2'": "Art.artistID" must be a "Artist" instance.

My first line of data looks like this:

```
1,2,Wisdom & Knowledge,Main Library,College,Visiting Artist at DTCC 19??-19??,Stone Sculpture,,
```

I fixed two errors before getting to this stuck point.  I added **db_column='artistID'**  and **default = 1** to the Art model's ArtistID field.  The default = 1 refers to an unknown artist in case the artist is unknown for a piece of art.

Can someone explain what the error message means, some hints on how to fix it, or an easier way to import .csv data into an existing Django model?

Thanks in advance!
Andrea

Comment: Tried the `django-import-export` module?

Comment: I looked at it and got overwhelmed!  I may have to look at it again.

Comment: that module makes it quite easy to import csv files into django databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Rakesh's help, I figured out how to do it.  The following view works:

```
def importArt(request):
    myFile = open('misc/Art.csv', 'r')
    for line in myFile:
        line = line.split(',')
        temp = Art.objects.create()
        temp.artID = line[0]
        if line[1] != '':
            temp.artistID = Artist.objects.get(pk = (line[1]))
        else:
            temp.artistID = Artist.objects.get(pk = 1)
        if line[2] != '':
            temp.title = line[2]
        else:
            temp.title = "Unknown"
        temp.location = line[3]
        temp.owner = line[4]
        temp.origin = line[5]
        temp.medium = line[6]
        temp.artNotes = line[7]
        temp.save()
    myFile.close()
    return render(request, 'dtccArt/importArt.html', {})
```

The ArtistID and Title are required fields, so I hard-coded in "Unknown" for the missing Title.  The PK = 1 artist has Unknown as its name.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
temp.artistID = line[1]
```

to

```
temp.artistID = Artist.objects.get(int(line[1]))
```

Comment: Now I get the error:  cannot unpack non-iterable int object.  Any ideas?

Comment: I tried this, which seems to have worked with non-blank data:  temp.artistID = Artist.objects.get(pk = (line[1])).  how do you make required fields use the default value when blank?

Answer (score -1):

With Rakesh and ajwong4 anwsers I came up with this General solution using pandas

*Rakesh and ajwong4 Thank You very much !*

Here,the general solution code

```
#First define your Django Enviromental variables

import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "DjangoProjectName.settings")
import django
django.setup()
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

   
#Import Required Django model

from djangoApp.models import * #models

# Import CSV file
df = pd.read_csv('csv_url.csv')

# Do required pre-processing on panda dataframe 
# such as data cleaning, data format settings etc..

# Iterater throught panda dataframe and save data in Django model

for index, row in df.iterrows():

      # create django model

      samplemodelObject = SampleModel()

      # Normal Fields ( Non-foreign key fields) adding
     
      samplemodelObject.field_name01 = row['Field_01']

      
      # Adding Foreign Key Field

       samplemodelObject.field_foreignkey = ForeignKeyModel.objects.get( fk_key = row['fk_value_field']

      # save data model instance
      samplemodelObject.save()
      samplemodelObject.clear()
```